# Creating phpMyAdmin error #1064

Tags: sql, enums, phpmyadmin

I was following a youtube tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEdQn3f23Xw). Even though I followed it to a t. The problem being is it didn't work because I have an updated version. I hope you can help. The SQL preview is here:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_database`.`members` 
 ( 
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `country` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `county/state` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `city` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `bio` TEXT NOT NULL , 
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    `signupdate` DATETIME NOT NULL , 
    `lastlogin` DATETIME NOT NULL , 
    `accounttype` ENUM(0) NOT NULL , 
    `emailactivated` ENUM(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\'0\'' , 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`), UNIQUE (`email`)
 ) 
 ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

This was the error message I received: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

```
'0) NOT NULL , `emailactivated` ENUM(0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\'0\'' , PRIMARY KE
```

at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your query like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test_database.members 
( 
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    country_state VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    country VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    city VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    bio TEXT NOT NULL , 
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , 
    signupdate DATETIME NOT NULL , 
    lastlogin DATETIME NOT NULL , 
    accounttype ENUM('0') NOT NULL , 
    emailactivated ENUM('0') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' , 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), UNIQUE (email)
) 
ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

try to use _ instead of/for column name. or just use camel case. Sometimes if you use /. It will give you an error.

for enum column type, it just like you give a choice, so better give the choice after that. like **`ENUM('a', 'b', 'c') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'a'`**

Instead. What Version of MySQL did you use? And Also for phpMyAdmin ?. Sometimes there is also a bug.
Read [link](https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/changelog.php)

Answer (score 0):

you cant set enum(0) that what wrong

> [check this if you want use enum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html)